# Sorting of isometric SKTileMapNode incorrect?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, tiled

I'm programmatically using `SKTileMapNode`. The code is C# (Xamarin.iOS) but should be readable by every Swift/ObjC developer.

The problem is that the sorting of tiles in isometric projection seems to be incorrect and I cannot see why. To test, the map has 1 row and 5 columns.

See the screenshot:

[image: Sorting]

The tiles at 0|0 and 2|0 are in front of the others. The pyramid styled tile at 4|0 however, is drawn correctly in front of the one at 3|0.

I'm using two simple tiles:

[image: Tile1]
[image: Tile2]

The first one has a resolution of 133x83px and the second one is 132x131px

This is what it looks like in Tiled and what I am trying to reproduce:

[image: Tiled]

The tile map is setup and added to the scene using the following code:

```
var tileDef1 = new SKTileDefinition (SKTexture.FromImageNamed ("landscapeTiles_014"));
var tileDef2 = new SKTileDefinition (SKTexture.FromImageNamed ("landscapeTiles_036"));

var tileGroup1 = new SKTileGroup (tileDef1);
var tileGroup2 = new SKTileGroup (tileDef2);

var tileSet = new SKTileSet (new [] { tileGroup1, tileGroup2 }, SKTileSetType.Isometric);

var tileMap =  SKTileMapNode.Create(tileSet, 5, 2, new CGSize (128, 64));

tileMap.Position = new CGPoint (0, 0);

tileMap.SetTileGroup (tileGroup1, 0, 0);
tileMap.SetTileGroup (tileGroup2, 1, 0);
tileMap.SetTileGroup (tileGroup1, 2, 0);
tileMap.SetTileGroup (tileGroup2, 3, 0);
tileMap.SetTileGroup (tileGroup2, 4, 0);

tileMap.AnchorPoint = new CGPoint (0, 0);
Add (tileMap);
```

If first suspected an incorrect tile size. The tile size used to initialise the tile map (128|64) is the size of the diamond shaped base of the tile. If using a flat tile, this is identical to the texture size. For tiles with a height, it differs. However, changing the tile size affects the alignment of the tiles an the size I'm using is the same as in Tiled and it's giving the correct result, so that cannot be the culprit.

What am I doing wrong or where am I thinking wrong?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong or where am I think wrong"? Probably hoping Apple's first release of a new API has been tested.

Comment: Unfortunately Apple seems to do very little internal testing of Sprite Kit and SceneKit. Each release brings new features, and new bugs. And this has been going on for so long that very few uses test their API betas. They just suppose they'll be busted and wait, plodding on with older stuff. And..: they are TERRIBLE at responding to bug reports... and their bug report system is a nightmare to use. It makes web 1.0 sites look up-to-date.

Comment: Just curious what is your `ignoresSiblingOrder` set to?

Comment: You mean of the view I'm adding to @MobileBen? I tried both variations. No  difference.

Comment: Have you looked at the adjacency masks? I haven't used SKTileMapNodes but I have worked on tile based games. You usually have to encode draw order. There are also usually layers on the tiles (eg. ground then other items)

Comment: `SKTileMapNode` is supposed to take care of the sorting and there is only one layer in my example. The tiles themselves are not nodes when using this new feature, so there is no z-order.

Comment: @Krumelur Links to your screenshots are broken, but it seems that I am facing the same issue. I use non-flat tiles (i.e. http://opengameart.org/content/isometric-landscape) and the z-order is all messed up. So I am stuck with flat tiles (like in the example Xcode tile set). It really seems to be a bug... The only workaround I have found is to build the map yourself using a grid of SKSpriteNode

Comment: Images are working fine here. But yes, I ended up creating my own isometric map.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for the main issue, but the tile size you use to initialise the map (128|64) is the size of the base tile, used to convert isometric coordinates into the the actual orthogonal space.

If you change this size in Tiled, it'll affect the size of the positioning grid. You can see a similar effect in Xcode's built-in tile map editor (or in any other isometric tile map editor I guess).

Comment: True. So that just just contributes to my suspicions that we're facing a bug here.